# Google TV video screen capture

Tags: android, television

Is there a possibility to take a screen capture using Google TV/Android SDK/API? I just need to get the screen into memory and get the dominant RGB color.

Comment: you can find your answer here [screen capture][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067586/how-to-capture-the-android-device-screen-content

Answer (score 1):

and here is the solution to get dominant RGB color [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530426/how-can-i-find-dominant-color-of-an-image) 
 and u can also try this

```
Bitmap bitmap;
View view1 = MyView.getRootView();
view1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view1.getDrawingCache());
view1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a screen capture of what is displayed on the TV - not just your app - you will set up ADB and use DDMS.  The steps to do that on a Google TV and a computer with ADB set up are:

1. Get the IP address of your computer.  On a Mac, use ifconfig
2. Go to the settings app on the TV.  Choose **Applications** and then
   **Developent** from the menu.
3. Set **Remote debugging** to true by enabling the checkbox
4. Set the **Debugger IP address** to the IP address of your computer from step 1
5. Go to the **Network** Menu under settings on the TV
6. Choose **Status** and note the IP Address of the TV

On your computer:
Connect the debugger to the computer using:
*adb connect xxx.xxx.x.104* using the IP address for the TV received in step x
Now your debugger is connected to the TV.  You can use DDMS and screen capture tool

Answer (score 0):

The main question here is: "Is it possible to make an application that will be run in backgroud and will only send some http packets based on the dominant RGB color of the video screenshot?"

There are also others factors like:
1. No root needed.
2. How fast screen capture operation is on google tv system? Probaby it depends on the hardware used.

Does anyone tried to take screen capture on google tv?