# How can I change the color of my text based on the color of the ImageView it overlays?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, imageview, color-detection

So I've got transparant buttons with white text labels set up over a user uploaded `ImageView`. If the user uploads an image that is mostly white, then the buttons are hard to see if not completely invisible.

Does anyone know of a way to get the average color of a `ImageView`'s source picture/drawable? If I can do this, I can compare it to a certain threshold I can trial and error for... If I can get this, then I can change the color of the text on my buttons to the inverted version of this color...or something??

Just idea spitting here..

And of course, if someone knows a better way, more info would be much appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: Check this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408431/how-can-i-get-the-average-colour-of-an-image

Comment: *...a better way...* - you could use a transparent gradient background to protect the buttons against the image like it is explained in the material design guidelines https://material.google.com/style/imagery.html#imagery-ui-integration (text-protection). As one of the answer mentions you could extract the colors with the Palette library but you still don't get 100% protection as you could end up in the image with a piece of white background right below the buttons

Comment: @Luksprog yes, I thought about that but I figured this could be a temp fix.  Adding a gradient overlay is a good idea, I'll consider doing this instead. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [Palette](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html) class.

From the [developers guide](https://developer.android.com/training/material/drawables.html#ColorExtract):

> You can retrieve the prominent colors from the image using the getter
>   methods in the `Palette` class, such as `Palette.getVibrantColor()`.

`Palette.from()` expects a `Bitmap` param, so you'll have to get it from your `ImageView`.

Something like this should work:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
Palette colorPalette = Palette.from(bitmap).generate();
```

And then you can call the appropriate methods on this `Palette` instance to get the prominent colors, for example:

```
int darkVibrantColor = colorPalette.getDarkVibrantColor(someDefaultColor);
```

Check out this example screenshot on how the `Palette` class recognizes colors:

[image]

Comment: Very nice, thanks! I'll see if I can get this in tomorrow. I'll get back to ya

Answer (score 1):

You can use Palette to get color of bitmap in an imageview

```
    bitmap = BitmapFactory
                    .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.header);

            Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {

                     //Set normal shade to textview
                    int vibrantColor = palette.getVibrantColor(R.color.primary_500);

                     //Set darkershade to textview
                    int vibrantDarkColor = palette
                            .getDarkVibrantColor(R.color.primary_700);


                }
            });
```

Comment: Yes it is working fine , where you think is the problem

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center"
            android:background="@drawable/noimage"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:text="Upload image"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:background="#34000000" />

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can set transparent color to button view . So button text is visible even if image is in white color. If its okay dont forget to thumb up answer!!

Comment: I think you misunderstood.  The button background is transparent, but the button text is visible.  The problem is that the button text is white, so when the imageview that my button is on top of has a white background, you can't see the button.  My goal is to change the button's text from white to black or something else whenever the background color is white (or whitish)

Comment: okay, then you should extract color from image and based on that you have to change text color,  you can refer this sample "https://chris.banes.me/2014/07/04/palette-preview/" @Ripyde4